# SuiteScript Access Custom Field in Sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have added two fields to the contact sublist record of customers. Two boolean values. I checked the values to make sure that they would show but in code cannot access those values in SS 1 or SS 2 through a sublist line item, I am accessing like this "var statements = rec.getLineItemValue( 'contactroles', 'custentity_statements', "1" );". When I look in the object for the customer record and look in the "contactroles" sublist, I cannot see those columns. If I load the contact record in SS 1 I can see the columns. Any help with this would be great, I would like to do it in SS 2 but I am flexible, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this helps, but you can retrieve the contact id, then load the contact record and check the field value.  This is assuming the custom field showing in the contact sublist is a contact field.  The documentation isn't too swift, but it looks as though not all sublist fields are supported for getFieldValue.  This is in SS1, but if it does what you want we should be able to take the same idea and write it in SS2.

```
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('customer','11499');
var conId = rec.getLineItemValue('contactroles', 'contact', 1);
var con = nlapiLoadRecord('contact',conId);
var statements = con.getFieldValue('custentity9');
console.log(statements); //T
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, pulling the contact record is prohibitive as I am working with datasets. This had occurred to me but I was hopeing to get an all in one go solution. As far as the fields, I have determined why that is. It seems that while you can add an ancilliary records fields to the line item they are accessible. I think there is an underlying record that the line item is based on through a saved search, I don't think columns added to records other than the base record can be manipulated.

Comment: Looks like this was the only option, thanks and sorry for taking so long to follow up with this question